# C# - Conversion -Clarification

Tags: c#

This could be a very basic question for prodigies.But I have a doubt to handle it.

During Conversion we are using :



*int.Parse(someThing)*



*Convert.ToInt32 or Convert.ToString()....*




  *(Int32)(someValue)*




*even we use  **"as"*** 



What are the restrictions for using each?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the .NET BCL documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

int.Parse assumes a string as a parameter and as such is only suitable for converting raw string representations to integers

Convert.ToInt32() will attempt to convert pretty much any object to an integer representation. Where the representation isn't a valid int (i.e. using a float with the value 55.3 or a string containing a word) this will raise a FormatException. If the integer is too large to fit in an int then an OverflowException will occur.

(int) is a direct cast. It's basically saying "I know that this object is really an integer, treat it as such". If the object actually isnt an integer you'll get an invalid cast exception.

Finally, as behaves the same as a direct cast except where the object is not of the correct type it will assign null. Not sure how this applies to int with it being a non-nullable type but certainly usable with

```
int? myInt = someVar as int?;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToNnnn` has the restrictions stipulated by its overloads; for instance, you cannot call `Convert.ToMyCustomType` (since that method does not exist). You can pass pretty much anything into `Convert.ToString` (or `Convert.ToInt32` or any other of the `Convert.ToNnnn` methods) but the result may not always make sense. Also, if the method fails to perform the conversion it may throw an `InvalidCastException`.

The regular type case (`(int)someValue`) can be used in all cases where there is an explicit conversion available. If you try to perform an illegal cast you will get an exception thrown at you.

The `as` keyword can be used to cast type to another (reference) type (and it will return null if it's not possible). The `as` keyword cannot be used with value types (such as `Int32`, `Point` or `DateTime`).

In my own code I typically use a mixture of them, but in general I follow the following scheme:

- If I want to convert a string to a numeric type, I usually use the `TryParse` provided by that numeric type.
- If I want to cast a class instance to a base class or interface, I usually use the `as` keyword.
- In other cases I use regular type casting within `try/catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32` can convert from various types (DateTime, Decimal, etc) back to an integer, while `int.Parse()` only converts from a string.

If you're only parsing strings back to integers, `Convert.ToInt32` is just an alias for `int.Parse`, so you might as well use `int.Parse` instead.

Regarding casting, you cannot cast a string to an integer, you have to **convert** it like mentioned above.

Consider that you are working with a database, and you have a column that is inefficiently declared as `varchar` while it stores integer data. You cannot do `(int)dr["column"]` when using a SqlDataReader for instance, you would have to use `int.Parse(dr["column"].ToString())` instead. If the column was of the `int` column type in the database, you could then have used the cast: `(int)dr["column"]`.